# Conditionally apply a ! to a method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Not sure how better to word this (and, consequently, couldn't find previous answers, though I expect this has been answered before), but I'm interested in whether there's a way to turn code like this:

```
if ( this.props.mailboxFilter == 'sent' ) {
  return this.currentUser.canActOnBehalfOf( m.senderID );
} else {
  return !this.currentUser.canActOnBehalfOf( m.senderID );
}
```

To something like the below (not sure how better to express it):

```
var bangOrNot = this.props.mailboxFilter == 'sent ? '!' : '';
bangOrNot( this.currentUser.canActOnBehalfOf( m.senderID ) );
```

As in, is there a way to avoid the extended if/else syntax and all the repetition by choosing whether or not to call the `return` line with a bang?

Comment: The solution might be elsewhere in your logic. Do you really want to send the inverse of the permissions? That seems weird.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could simplify it in other ways:

```
var response = this.currentUser.canActOnBehalfOf(m.senderID);
return this.props.mailboxFilter == 'sent' ? response : !response;
```

In general, you would want to avoid this method if your function changes any state. However, since in this case you are calling it regardless, there's no harm in caching its value first.

Answer (score 5):

If `this.currentUser.canActOnBehalfOf( m.senderID )` allways returns a boolean value, you could do XOR.

```
return (this.props.mailboxFilter != 'sent') ^ this.currentUser.canActOnBehalfOf(m.senderID);
```

XOR a boolean value with `true` makes a NOT. And XOR with `false` makes a buffer which maintains the same value.

Note that I changed the `==` to `!=`.

And, just make sure you put comments on this part of the code if you are going to use it actually. It is not that easy to read this code after a while.

**Update**

As [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) suggested, it is better to use Boolean XOR `!=` to return a boolean value.

```
return (this.props.mailboxFilter != 'sent') != this.currentUser.canActOnBehalfOf(m.senderID);
```

And of course if it can be used with boolean XNOR as well, just replace both `!=`s with `==` in the code above.

Comment: This is the most efficient way.

Comment: I like this... but your future self won't!

Comment: @Xophmeister Of course :)

One can use this to maximize his job security! No one else can read this code!

Comment: This returns a number, not a boolean.

Comment: I was going to answer it this way too, until @Bergi had the obvious and elegant equivalence operator. If it was done this way with a bit-wise XOR, it just needs to be cast to a bool before being returned wrap in brackets and prepend '!!'

Comment: @JamesWakefield: If it was done with XOR, you just should use the boolean XOR: `!=` :-)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the boolean XNOR operator here - also known as *equivalence*:

```
return this.currentUser.canActOnBehalfOf(m.senderID) == (this.props.mailboxFilter == 'sent');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many good comments regarding why or why NOT to do such thing.  I'm assuming the OP has good reason to want to apply the bang (!) in front of the result of the function call.  My answer is more of a technical solution to the OP's question.

```
function bang(r) {
    return !r;
}
function notBang(r) {
    return r;
}
function canActOnBehalf() {
    return true;
}
var filter = 'notsent';
var f = (filter == 'sent' ? bang : notBang);
f(canActOnBehalf('whatever'));
```

Answer (score -4):

Assuming you're using javascript, you can use the `eval` method to evaluate a string of javascript code. You can conditionally apply the bang to the front of the string and then return the result of `eval`.

Comment: Why not? This is not to challenge you I'm seriously curious.

Comment: Neither comment is constructive. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: There's lots of articles on it from people way more knowledgeable than me. It's one of those things that's drilled in as bad practice in almost any case. @isherwood's link is good.

Comment: Ok I understand there is a risk of injection but in this case he would not be allowing the user to input any of the code used in `eval`. I don't see the risk.

Comment: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html

Comment: I think I'll go with Xophmeister's answer, which makes sense and isn't "evil", but I really don't see what's wrong with William Rosenbloom's `eval` version, or get why it needs to be down-voted as opposed to just not used/upvoted. Just my 2 cents. It may not be a blanket "best solution", but it doesn't open any of the "bad" doors mentioned in the links pasted, apart from the slight speed issue. It's using `eval` for a pretty unique purpose. At any rate, thanks for all the thoughts/feedback.